# Strange Behavior with strings.TrimSuffix \n

Tags: go, newline, stdin

I am trying to remove the \n from a filename read from keyboard, but the generated concatenated path is strange.

( Go 1.11 on windows )

```
fmt.Println("Enter file name:")
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

//read line from console
filename, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
//filename = filename[0 : len(filename)-2] // this one seems to work
filename = strings.TrimSuffix(filename, "\n")
fmt.Println("1" + filename + "2")
```

Entering ABC and newline produces the following output, erasing the 1 :

> Enter file name:
>
> ABC
>
> 2ABC

What's going on here? My guess is that my \n is actually a 2 character CRLF, and TrimSuffix is not handling it correctly. Is that the problem?

Comment: "My guess is that my \n is actually a 2 character CRLF, and TrimSuffix is not handling it correctly. Is that the problem?" that seems incredibly easy to check for yourself. Have you?

Comment: You are also silencing the error returned from `ReadString`. It is probably nil but you cannot be sure until you test it. Do Not Ever Silence Errors.

Comment: from the ReadString docs: `ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter. If ReadString encounters an error before finding a delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error itself (often io.EOF). ReadString returns err != nil if and only if the returned data does not end in delim. For simple uses, a Scanner may be more convenient.` -> You might be hitting EOF instead of a newline. No way to know since you silenced error.

Comment: Yes you are right about ignoring a possible error. But I did check it, and no error is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strings.TrimSpace(string) string`:

```
fmt.Println("Enter file name:")
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

//read line from console
filename, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
filename = strings.TrimSpace(filename)
fmt.Println("1" + filename + "2")
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LrahJcWIQWB)

Comment: Thanks, this worked, while TrimSuffix did not. In an unrelated matter, is my question really so horrible that it merits a -4 score? I wonder about this site sometimes.